# Barplot showing abnormal values in x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set as follows,

```
data1

  date_value       value
      (date)       (dbl)
1 2016-06-22       72.30
2 2016-06-23       64.46
3 2016-06-24       49.25
```

I want to plot this in a bar graph and following is the code,

```
ggplot(aes(x = date_value, y = value), data = data1) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

but I am getting the following graph, were the X-axis is corrupted with some values. From the below picture, we can see that the x-axis is not having proper values and disturbed by others. Can anybody help me in solving what is the problem?

[image]

Comment: I cannot replicate. Can you make sure include a `dput()` of your `data1`? What versions of R/ggplot2/dplyr are you using?

Comment: data1 <- data.frame(date_value = as.Date(c("2016-06-22", "2016-06-23", "2016-06-24"), origin = "1970-01-01"),
                    value = c(72.3, 64.46, 49.25))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your date labels are trying to be displayed as datetime values. Try this:

```
ggplot(aes(x = date_value, y = value), data = data1) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + scale_x_date(date_labels="%b %d")
```

[image]